# gulp permission and local install without the json file

Tags: json, node.js, npm, gulp

As it says on the [gulp io](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md) to install gulp globally you need to run

```
npm i -g gulp
```

which will return an EACCES error so you will use sudo in front of the command. Now I go into my new project directory that I want to install gulp in. As they say on the page to install it into your project folder you can use this command

```
npm i --save-dev gulp
```

if I do so it returns an EACCES error, which means I will need to use sudo again which I cannot quite get as I only want to install it in a local directory. If I do so it installs node_modules folder with path

```
gulp@3.9.0 ../../node_modules/gulp
```

Which means it is installed in my root directory and not the directory I wanted it to install it in. To fix it I can run

```
npm init
```

saying yes to everything and then

```
sudo npm install --save-dev gulp
```

Which will put node_modules into my project folder

My question is what prevents gulp installation into my project folder be as simple as it is in the gulp instruction? And what can I do to prevent this from happening in the future? I have researched this and people seem to get gulp running without the package.json file which is not a big deal but one more step if you want to jump start on something.

Comment: Check permission on your project folder your user probably cannot write in.

Comment: it has 755 permissions so the user can read, write and execture